# Why am I getting this error: Do not call Hooks inside useEffect(...), useMemo(...), or other built-in Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to react but I've encountered enough errors to know not to call Hooks inside useEffect(...), useMemo(...), or other built-in Hooks

I'm trying to import data from mongodb atlas into my app.
From the codes written below, I don't think it has violated the rule. Any help would be great thx!

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";


const Events = () => {
  const [allEvents, setEvents] = useState([]);
  const fetchEvents = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/get/events`);
      return data
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchEvents();
  }, []);
};

export default Events;
```

[image: Error msg]

```
function CalendarComponent() {
  //useState declarations
  const [newEvent, setNewEvent] = useState({
    id: "",
    title: "",
    start: "",
    action: "",
  });
  const [allEvents, setEvents] = useState(events);
  const [toggleAdd, setToggleAdd] = useState(false);
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState("");

  //handle creating new event on button click
  function handleAddSlot() {
    const title = newEvent.title;
    const start = newEvent.start;
    const end = start;
    let success = 0;
    if (title && newEvent.action === control.ADD) {
      // add new event into the list
      const id = allEvents.length;

      if(data.Events.some(i=>i["Serial Number"]===title)){
        // let newArr = [...data.Events]
        // const res = newArr.find(e=>e["Serial Number"]===title)["Scheduled Sample Date"]
        // console.log(res);
        // res.push({id:res.length,start,end})
        data.Events.map(item=>item["Serial Number"]===title?{...item}["Scheduled Sample Date"].push({"id":{...item}["Scheduled Sample Date"].length,start}):item)


      }
      else{
        setEvents((prev) => [...prev, { start, end, title }]);
      }
      setToggleAdd(true);
      console.log(data.Events)
      success = 1;
    }
    if (newEvent.action === control.UPDATE) {
      // find id of existing event to update
      setEvents((currEvents) =>
        currEvents.map((event) => {
          
          if (event.id === newEvent.id) {
            return {
              ...event,
              start: start,
              end: start,
              title: title,
            };
          } else {
            return event;
          }
        })
      );
      success = 1;
      console.log(allEvents);
    }
    // if action successful, close modal and clear all fields
    if (success === 1) {
      setToggleAdd(false);
      clearFields();
    }
  }
  // handle when user select existing scope event
  function handleSelectEvent(event) {
    setMsg("Update Scope");
    const start = new Date(event.start);
    setNewEvent({
      ...newEvent,
      action: control.UPDATE,
      title: event.title,
      start,
      id: event.id,
    });
    setToggleAdd(true);
  }

  //handle calendar slot click
  function handleClick(e) {
    newEvent.start = e.start;
    newEvent.action = control.ADD;
    setMsg("Add New Scope");
    if (
      // ? Can be better written
      document.getElementById("id01")?.classList.contains("setDisplay") === true
    ) {
      setToggleAdd(true);
    }
  }
  //handle modal close when user clicks on x
  function toggleClick() {
    if (toggleAdd === true) {
      setToggleAdd(false);
      clearFields();
    }
  }
  //function to clear all fields
  function clearFields() {
    newEvent.start = "";
    newEvent.title = "";
  }
  return (
    <div className={`calendar-container`}>
      <AddModal
        id="id01"
        toggle={toggleAdd}
        newEvent={newEvent}
        toggleClick={toggleClick}
        handleSelectSlot={handleAddSlot}
        setNewEvent={setNewEvent}
        msg={msg}
      />

      <Calendar
        localizer={localizer}
        events={allEvents}
        popup
        defaultView="month"
        longPressThreshold={1}
        views={["month"]}
        eventPropGetter={(event) => {
          const identifier = data.Events.find(
            (item) => item["Type"] === event.type
          );
          const backgroundColor = identifier
            ? data.Color.find((item) => item[`${identifier.Type}`])[
            `${identifier.Type}`
            ]
            : "";
          return { style: { backgroundColor } };
        }}
        onSelectEvent={handleSelectEvent}
        onSelectSlot={(e) => handleClick(e)}
        selectable
        style={{ height: 500, margin: "30px" }}
        components={{
          toolbar: CustomToolbar,
        }}
      />
      <div className="calendar-sidebar">
        <Button text="Add New" button="button" onClick={handleClick} />
        <Log type='Schedule' />
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

I've attached the CalendarComponent. I can't really seem to find the problem in CalendarComponent myself. Hopefully it's not in the react big calendar package and I'm not missing something

Comment: The problem isn't in the code you've shown. Please update the question with a [mre], preferably a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: telling by the call-stack, I'd take a look at the `CalendarComponent`

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I've added the calendar component!

Comment: Actually i realized my mistake. >>  const [allEvents, setEvents] = useState(events); Although I'm still lost as to how i should go about adding my database data into my app

Comment: You don't show us how you use `Events`. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before making additional questions. `Events` doesn't return any react elements, so it's not a component. You're probably calling `Evens` in an unexpected place, that you don't show us.